# How to obtain a group membership time evolution from login date / logout date table in mysql

Tags: mysql, loops

a newcomer to mysql here:
I have a members table with Name, login_date and logout_date columns.

| Name | login_date | logout_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2004-01-08 00:00:00 | 2004-01-10 00:00:00 |
| Mary | 2004-01-09 00:00:00 | 2005-05-31 00:00:00 |
| Frank | 2004-01-12 00:00:00 | 2005-11-08 00:00:00 |
| Nancy | 2004-01-12 00:00:00 | 2007-10-13 00:00:00 |
| Louise | 2004-01-16 00:00:00 | 2011-09-30 00:00:00 |

I want to know the evolution of membership over a period of time so using 2 dates (first_date and last_date) as limits to get the number of members in the group each day in the range (first_date,last_date)

Can it be done in mysql? Any clue will be very much appreciated

Cheers.

The following query gets the number of members in a particular date (@mydate)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE login_date <= @mydate and logout_date>= @mydate
```

I want to have something like this given 2 dates:
@myfirstdate = '2004-01-08 00:00:00'
@mylastdate = '2004-01-16 00:00:00'

| Date | Members # |
| --- | --- |
| 2004-01-08 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2004-01-09 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2004-01-10 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2004-01-11 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2004-01-12 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2004-01-13 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2004-01-14 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2004-01-15 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2004-01-16 00:00:00 | 4 |

But I don't know how to do it in mysql if it is at all possible.

Comment: This will generate a series of dates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WITH RECURSIVE` to generate days between two dates:

```
    WITH RECURSIVE days AS (
        SELECT '2004-01-08' AS login_date
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATE_ADD(login_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS value
        FROM days
        WHERE days.login_date < '2004-01-16'
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM days;
```

Then join it with your table using `inner join`.

This is the query :

```
   WITH RECURSIVE days AS (
        SELECT '2004-01-08' AS login_date 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATE_ADD(login_date , INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS login_date 
        FROM days
        WHERE days.login_date  < '2004-01-16'
    )
    SELECT d.login_date, count(1)
    FROM days d
    inner join member_name mn on d.login_date between mn.login_date and mn.logout_date
    group by d.login_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this version of mysql (5.5.62) doesn't support WITH RECURSIVE. Do you think there is another way to do it?

Comment: Can you have a look to my new answer

Answer (score 0):

I choose to Create an other query for anyone using mariadb.

We can use seq_8_to_16 to generate dates we wants,

This `select seq from seq_8_to_16;` will generate numbers from 8 to 16.
For example, to generate the sequence of integers from 1 to 100, do this :

```
select seq from seq_1_to_100;
```

So our query will be as follows :

```
select d.login_date, count(1)
from member_name mn
inner join (
    SELECT concat('2004-01-', if(seq<10, concat('0',seq) ,seq)) as login_date
    FROM seq_8_to_16 d
) as d on d.login_date between mn.login_date and mn.logout_date
group by d.login_date;
```

Comment: There is no `seq_8_to_16` in MySql.

Comment: You are right Its only on mariadb, I made a mistake, I will edit my answer

Comment: @SelVazi Thanks for sharing MariaDB Sequence Storage Engine information.